# How to Check the iPad current version for Camera actions?

Tags: ipad, camera

Am new to iPad application. I want to access ipad camera for my application, but ipad2 it have the camera, so i want to check out the current version of ipad to access camera option. How to check it. Can any one help me. Thanks for reading my poor english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of checking for iPad version you can check if the source is available or not. By doing so you dont have to worry about the version, and it will also take care or situations like if you are making your app for iPhone or iPod too

```
if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = sourceType;
    picker.delegate = self;
    if(sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
        [picker takePicture];
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mr.Robin. But iPad1 does not ve a camera option. This code can help me on ipad1. can you understand my problem. iPad2 only having camera options.

Comment: @Yuvaraj This method works on the iPad1, even though it doesn't have a camera.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a litle problem with IPAD 2 because it has two camreas and when i try to get default it always gets the backcamera. in some Application is shows a button on screen which allows me to choose front or back camera.

Detect it using

```
picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
```

Or

```
picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
```

Comment: did u solved your front and back camera problem. How to solve this. Can you help me.

Comment: IT is easir to detect using `picker.cameraDevice =  UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;`
OR 
`UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront`

Comment: Thank you very much. I implemented your idea in my application. U saved my day.